# Rails: How to combine association and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to get all the TaskInteractions of type "offer" for a specific user.

I have a User model

```
has_many :task_interactions
```

and a TaskInteraction model

```
belongs_to :user
```

TaskInteraction has an attribute "type" which can have the value offer or quiz.

Currently, I'm using a scope

```
scope :offer_interactions, -> { where(type: 'offer') }
```

And I get the result

```
@user.task_interactions.offer_interactions
```

Or in the User model I could define:

```
def offer_interactions
  self.task_interactions.where(type: 'offer')
end
```

Or if I combine the scope and the offer_interactions method:

```
def offer_interactions
  self.task_interactions.offer_interactions
end
```

Questions:

Is there a better way to get to this result?

Is there Rails way for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add in the User model a scoped `has_many` relation, to only take into account the offer task_interactions:

`has_many :offer_interactions, -> { where(type: 'offer') }, class_name: 'TaskInteraction'`

And then just call `@user.offer_interactions`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.